How to Safely Deploy and Migrate a PostgreSQL Prisma Schema to a Production Database with Docker, EC2, and AWS RDS Without Downtime?
I am working on deploying the latest changes from our staging environment to our production environment. We’re using PostgreSQL with Prisma for database management, and our setup involves Docker containers running on an EC2 instance. Here’s a detailed overview of our architecture and workflow, along with some questions about the correct approach for running Prisma migration commands to avoid breaking the production environment.
Environment Details
Staging Environment:

Database: NeonDB (PostgreSQL)
ORM: Prisma

Schema changes were made directly in NeonDB, and then prisma db pull was run to sync these changes with our local environment. This approach was used to avoid data loss: if we had modified the schema model file locally and run prisma migrate dev, Prisma would have prompted a warning about potential data loss. By updating the schema directly in NeonDB and pulling it locally, we minimized this risk.
Production Environment:

Database: AWS RDS PostgreSQL
Hosted on AWS EC2 with Docker containerization

Three Docker containers: one for the backend (Node.js + Prisma), one for the frontend (React), and one for a Python service

Our EC2 instance has a Dockerfile for building the images.

Goal
We need to migrate our updated Prisma schema from staging to the production database (AWS RDS PostgreSQL) and deploy the latest backend code without causing downtime or breaking the production environment.
Steps I Followed:

Merged the latest changes from the staging branch to the main branch.

Connected to our EC2 instance via SSH and navigated to the project directory


cd /opt/recruiterai-backend

Ran sudo git pull to pull the latest code from the repository, which was successful.

After pulling the latest code, I attempted to run prisma migrate deploy directly in the project directory (recruiterai-backend) on the EC2 server (without getting inside the container). However, I encountered an error stating “bash: command not found.”


Note: I did not run prisma migrate dev either on the server or locally before attempting prisma migrate deploy on the EC2 server.
Questions

Where to Run prisma migrate dev?


Should we run prisma migrate dev on the local development machine to generate the migration files, or should this command be run on the EC2 server itself?

Is there any risk to running prisma migrate dev on the server, or is it only intended for development environments?



Where to Run prisma migrate deploy?


Should prisma migrate deploy be run inside the Docker container for the backend service? Or is there a recommended way to apply migrations on a production server using Prisma with Docker?

Since we are using Docker, Prisma and Node.js are set up inside the container, so I’m assuming this command would need to run inside the container, but I’d appreciate confirmation on the safest approach.


Proposed Steps for Deployment and Migration
Below are the steps I’m planning to follow for deploying and migrating the backend code and database schema changes. Could you please review and let me know if this is the correct approach, or suggest any improvements?

Generate Migration Files

Run prisma migrate dev on the local development machine to generate the migration files based on the latest schema changes:
npx prisma migrate dev --name "migration_name"
Commit and push the migration files to the main branch.

Merge the latest changes from the staging branch into the main branch.

SSH into the EC2 instance

Backup the Production Database using
pg_dump -U <your_username> -h <your_host> -p <your_port> -d <your_database_name> > backup.sql

Navigate to the project directory: cd /opt/recruiterai-backend

Pull Latest Code on EC2
In the EC2 instance, pull the latest code, which includes the migration files:
sudo git pull

Run Migration in the Current Backend Container:
Run prisma migrate deploy inside the currently running backend container to apply the migrations to the AWS RDS database:


docker exec -it <backend_container_id_or_name> npx prisma migrate deploy
Note: This ensures that the database schema is updated before deploying the new container.

Build the Docker Image
After applying the migration, build the Docker image with the latest code


docker build -t recruiterai-back-node:latest .

Start the Updated Container Using Docker Compose
docker-compose up -d

Finally Verify the Containers: docker ps


Concerns

Schema and Container Consistency: Will running prisma migrate deploy in the existing container and then rebuilding the image cause any inconsistencies, given that the migration was applied before the new container was started?

Error Prevention: Are there any additional best practices or precautions we should take to avoid potential errors or downtime during this process?


I want to confirm the correct places to run prisma migrate dev and prisma migrate deploy in a production environment with Docker and the correct order of steps to ensure a safe and downtime-free deployment.
Thank you for any guidance you can provide! We want to be absolutely certain about the process to avoid any disruption to production.

Please ask only one question at a time – there's quite a lot here.  Also remember that Stack Overflow questions need to be about programming and are often better-received if they're fairly specific; "how do I run migrations" can be a good question, but "how do I restore the database" is probably more appropriate on [sf] or [dba.se], and "will this cause inconsistencies" seems a little non-specific to be answerable.
